# Imperfect json return string from http request

Tags: ballerina

so i have created a service using ballerina and as a result it should give me a json string and it is however the string it is returning is not what i want

what it's returning :
{"value":{"iduser":1, "username":"doctor1", "password":"password1", "accessright":true, "acctype":"doctor"}}
what i want it to return :
{"iduser":1, "username":"doctor1", "password":"password1", "accessright":true, "acctype":"doctor"}

service code:
stream<record{}, error> resultStream =
jdbcClient->query(`SELECT * FROM user where username = ${username} and password= ${password} and acctype= ${acctype} and accessright=1;`);
record {} |error? result = resultStream.next();
return result;

Comment: btw consider putting the json in code fences to make it easier to read

Answer (score 1):

Calling `next()` on a stream `stream<T, C>` (where the values in the generated sequence are of type `T` and the completion type is `C`) will return `record {| T value; |}|C`.

Therefore when using `next()` with `stream<record{}, error>`, the returned value will be either `record {| record {} value; |}` or `error`. I believe this is why the value you expect is different from the actual value (i.e., part of another record as the `value` field). So in the non-error scenario, to access the actual value you need to access the `value` field.

```
record {| record {} value; |}|error next = resultStream.next();

if next is error {
    // Handle the error, no more values.
} else {
    // `record {| record {} value; |}` here.
    // The value field needs to be accessed to get the actual value.
    record {} value = next.value;
}
```

The value is returned as a field of a record to differentiate between the next value being returned vs the iteration/sequence completing. For example, if we have `stream<error, error?>`, we can still differentiate whether `next` returned an error because the next value in the sequence is an error vs due to the sequence completing.

```
stream<error, error?> st = new;

record {| error value; |}|error? next = st.next();

if next is error? {
    // Indicates end of the sequence.
} else {
    // `record {| error value; |}` here.
    // This is the next value in the sequence.
    error value = next.value;
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work it showed me this error on the last part of the code (next.value) 
invalid operation: type 'record {| record {| anydata...; |} value; |}?' does not support field access

Comment: This depends on the type of the `next` variable. According to the error message, it seems like it was defined with nil. If the `next` variable is defined as `record {record {} value;}|error?`, you can check if `next is error?` in the if block. Then in the else block the type of `next` will be `record {| record {| anydata...; |} value; |}` on which you can use field access.

Answer (score 0):

So, after hours of thinking it hit me that when we have multiple results from our mysql select query these results are not hidden under a value element so i just treated it as if i was gonna get multiple results knowing i only have one and then i took the first and only element in the array and sent it back
New Code:

```
stream<record{}, error> resultStream =
jdbcClient->query(`SELECT * FROM user where username = ${username} and password= ${password} and acctype= ${acctype} and accessright=1;`);
int i =0;
record{}[] aaaaa= [];
error? e=resultStream.forEach(function (record{} result2){
    aaaaa[i]=result2;
    i=i+1;
});
check jdbcClient.close();
return aaaaa[0];
```